# How to simulate jsp:param in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a jsp file with use `jsp:include` to include another jsp

```
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/bug/bugQueryFilter.jsp">
        <jsp:param value="bugFilterClick()" name="submitFun"/>
        <jsp:param value="collapseOne" name="collDIVName"/>
        <jsp:param value="bugSearchVO" name="parameterName"/>
    </jsp:include>
```

In the `bugQueryFilter.jsp` I use `${param.collDIVName}` to get the parameter.

Now I face a problem,I need to return `bugQueryFilter.jsp` in `SpringMVC` directly,but I do not know how to pass the parameter to it

```
public String changeFilter(HttpServletRequest request){
   request.setAttribute("collDIVName","collapseOne");//in this way ${param.collDIVName} will not get the parameter
   return "bugQueryFilter.jsp";
}
```

Now I want to know how the simulate jsp:param to pass parameter to the `bugQueryFilter.jsp` page directly?

Note:due to some reason,I can not change `${param.collDIVName}` to `${collDIVName}` when access parameter

I know I can create a new jsp page,and invoke `jsp:include` in the new jsp page,then return the new jsp page,however I think this is not an elegant way.

Can anyone help me,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try returning a `ModelAndView`?

e.g.

```
public ModelAndView changeFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:bugQueryFilter.jsp?collDIVName=collapseOne");
}
```

Comment: It works fine,thank you very much,according to your answer,I found that I just need to append parameter at the end of the jsp name `bugQueryFilter.jsp?collDIVName=collapseOne`